# Auto size for text view

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview

I have a text view and 3 buttons on my User Interface.
The first button sets the text of the text view to just one line of text.
(I also do this in the `viewDidLoad`)
The second button sets the text of the text view to 3 lines of text.
The third button sets the text of the text view to 5 lines of text.
The text view's size only fits one line of text.
How to change it's size every time I tap a button to fit the text hight?

Note : I am using ios 7.1

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextView is a subclass of UIView. You can call:

```
[myTextView sizeToFit];
```

To ensure that the view resizes to fit the contents as described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit

You can call:

```
[myTextView sizeToFit]
```

In the IBAction that your button is linked to, or the function that you have linked to the button as a selector.

Comment: And it will make my text view higher or shorter?